# in a group G where all elements are of order 3 show that $(ba)^2=a^2b^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is a problem from my algebra book stated as:

In a group G all elements is of order 3 except the neutral element. Show that $(ba)^2=a^2b^2$ for all $a,b \in G$

So I have $a$, $a^2$, $a^3=1$, $a^4=a$, same for $b$ and $a^3=1=b^3$.

At first I thought "except the neutral element" just meant that $a^3=1$ but now I'm not even sure about that so I guess I need some clarification about that.

Then I tried to solve it as follows:

$$(ba)^2=(ba)(ba)=b(ab)a=b(a^4b^4)a=..... $$

where I tried to manipulate the expression with various combinations of:

- $a=a^4=a  a^3 $
- Using inverses for example $a^2=a^{-1} $

But I'm not really getting anywhere except going around in a circle showing that $(ba)(ba)=(ba)(ba)$

Comment: Which textbook are you referring to?

Comment: It's a swedish book but the name is abstrakt algebra by Per-Anders Svensson

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have
$$
a^2b^2=a^{-1}b^{-1}=(ba)^{-1}=(ba)^2.
$$

Comment: Oh I forgot about that theorem that $a^{-n}=(a^n)^{-1} and I had the inverses. But now the solution was quite easy, thanks!

Comment: One question, in the step from $(ba)^{-1}=(ba)^2$ works because both $a^{-1}$, $b^{-1} \in G$ right?

Comment: No, that's not the argument. The argument is, that EVERY element $g\in G$ satisfies $g^2=g^{-1}$ by assumption, in particular $g=ba$.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since every element, except the identity, has order $3$, $\forall a\in G\ a^3=1$ (for $a\neq 1_G$ this follows from the assumption on the order, for $1_G$ this is trivial)
$$(ba)^2\cdot a^2b^2=baba\cdot a^2b^2=baba^3b^2=bab^3=ba=(ba)(ba)^3=(ba)^4\\
(ba)^2a^2b^2=(ba)^4\\
a^2b^2=(ba)^2
$$

Comment: Oh, so $(ba)^3$ is also equal to 1?

Comment: Yes, because $ba$ is an element of $G$ and so it either has order $3$ or it is the identity, and in both cases it satifies the equation

Comment: oh, never thought about that Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

By assumption (first equality), $e=(ba)^3=(ba)^2(ba)$, and then $(ba)^2=(ba)^{-1}=a^{-1}b^{-1}$. Now, $a^2b^2=a^{-1}b^{-1}$ if and only if $a^3b^3=e$, and this latter holds by assumption. Then indeed $(ba)^2=a^2b^2$.